# R - Violin plot x-axis names

Tags: r, graph, plot, legend

I am creating violin plots with lots (will be ~100) of columns (violins). The problem is that the name of each column is very long. What I am doing current is as follows:

```
jpeg("stats/AllDistanceViolinPlot.jpg", width = 1000, height = 1000);
do.call(vioplot, c(lapply(data, na.omit),list(names=c("veryveryveryverylongname1", "veryveryveryverylongname2", "veryveryveryverylongname4", "veryveryveryverylongname4", "veryveryveryverylongname5", "veryveryveryverylongname6", "veryveryveryverylongname7", "veryveryveryverylongname8"))));
dev.off()
```

Which gives me this plot:

[image]

As you can see, the names of the columns are very long and some actually are not shown. I have also tried something without the list:

```
jpeg("stats/plot.jpg", width = 1000, height = 1000);
do.call(vioplot, c(lapply(data, na.omit)));
dev.off()
```

Which gives me this plot:

[image]

What I'd like is one of two things:

1. The names of the columns would be vertical so that they are shown and aren't cut off
   or
2. Make the main plot like the second image I posted and have a separate legend that would correlate each column with the full name. For example, something like the following:

   1 - veryveryveryverylongname1
   2 - veryveryveryverylongname2
   ...
   8 - veryveryveryverylongname8

Could someone please suggest the better way (or both) and comment on how to implement them?

Greatly appreciated.

Comment: Care to provide a reproducible example?

Comment: I suppose that I could do a search and identify the package that has `vioplot`, but isn't that really your responsibility?

Comment: I have checked the vioplot package, but didn't see anything of the sort. That why I posted, to know if anyone else knows about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately the vioplot function in the vioplot package does not accept the usual base graphics parameters for modifying the orientation of axis annotation. You will need to make a new vioplot function and change this code:

```
if (!horizontal) {
    if (!add) {
        plot.window(xlim = xlim, ylim = ylim)
        axis(2)
        axis(1, at = at, label = label)
```

To this:

```
if (!horizontal) {
    if (!add) {
        plot.window(xlim = xlim, ylim = ylim)
        axis(2)
        axis(1, at = at, label = label , las=2)
```

Comment: @intl: Not need, just copy the code of the function and give it another name.